# How to Add Pardot Opportunity records in Pardot lists?

Tags: opportunity, automation, pardot

I have opportunity records in Pardot and want to add them in a Pardot list.
How can I achieve it, so that the list can be used in the engagement studio?
Also, is it possible to I search the SF opportunity records or Pardot List opportunity records in a engagement studio journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardot lists can contain a combination of: Prospects, Leads or Contacts.

Using a [dynamic list](https://www.pardot.com/blog/dynamic-lists/), you can create a list based on opportunity criteria. Therefore the list would only contain contacts (as a contact can only be associated with an opportunity). When a new contact meets the opportunity criteria they would be added to the list and if they no longer, the contact would be removed.

Below is an example of using opportunity criteria in a dynamic list:

[image: Pardot dynamic list opportunity criteria]

Currently, there is no rule option within engagement studio to check for an opportunity. However, this list above could be used as the input list for an engagement programme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, also is it possible to use opportunity records in Engagement studio input source?

Comment: Not opportunity records. But contacts related to them.

Comment: The contact has to be added as a contract role on the opportunity

Comment: but in this way the contact record would be the input source for the engagement program and not the opportunity record, right?

Comment: This is correct